# How can I improve duty cycle of Ne 555 timer to the 50% if I am generating triangle wave above 200 kHz?

Tags: oscillator

[image]

In this circuit I am generating a 200 kHz triangular wave, in real-time when I am performing I am getting a  triangular wave with duty cycle of 62%, I want a 50% duty cycle. How I can get it?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE Have you tried to adjust your timing capacitors and resistors?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CMOS version](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf?&ts=1590158329415) of the 555 (capable of several MHz maximum). The ancient bipolar version is very sluggish.

Alternatively, you can parallel R1 with a diode and another resistor to try to equalize ton and toff but it's not as nice.

Comment: I only want a duty cycle of approx 48-52% .please let me know what I can do , I also connected parallel R1 with a diode and another resistor , but still, the duty cycle didn't improve.

Comment: If it got worse, reverse the diode and try again.

Comment: Actually, I had reversed the diode, the output pin will not work, please give some options where I can improve

Comment: At ~200kHz the CMOS version is more appropriate

Comment: Thank you, sir, can you tell me which operational amplifier should I use for amplifying the signal with frequency is above 200khz.